# Gift giving and two levels of repeated measures

Tags: repeated-measures, social-network, social-science

The data comprise 1000+ observational hours of 110 women from a cultural group. Data were collected per observational day per woman. The women are from 10 camps at 10 different time points (over the course of 3 years).

Two levels of repeat measurements are present. 1) Women have repeat observation days. For example, Woman A may be observed 4 observation days during the one month visit to Camp 1. 2) Due to movement, 17 of the women appear at more than one camp site (16 appear at 2 camp sites and 1 at 3).

During their daily observations, the women sometimes gave or received gifts (food items). 1000+ gifts were recorded. For each gift, there is the item, its kcal amount, kin identification of giver, kin identification of receiver. For instance, gift giver marked as mother and gift receiver marked as child.

I seek to know who (mother, aunt, grandma etc) is most often giving to whom (frequency-wise) and who is giving the most to whom (kcal-wise). I also seek to answer more specific questions like are pregnant women receiving more gifts than non-pregnant women? Are nursing women receiving more gifts than non-nursing women?

What is the best statistical option for analyzing the gifts given the 2 types of repeated measures?